# Root user access for another user

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, root, visudo

I am trying to gain root user access to another user so that I can run a command with adding sudo in front of any command.

Example: `fdisk -l`

Getting the error message as:

```
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop0: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop1: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop2: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop3: Permission denied
```

I tried to give the root user access to the user with the name `sudhir`.

switched to root user with `su -`

```
visudoers
```

Added the user as

```
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
sudhir  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

[screenshot of the sudoers file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r4YL.png)

Saved with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>,
switched to user & executed the command `fdisk -l`, still getting the same error.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you remember to logout/login after changes to user permissions?

Comment: You must still type `sudo fdisk -l` as user sudhir.

Comment: Is your goal that all commands run by sudhir, even without `sudo`, run as if by root? This is inadvisable; e.g., users shouldn't run `firefox` or `libreoffice` as root (nor with abilities equivalent to root's). Even if you're not concerned about security, this would make some strange and unexpected mistakes easier to make. If you still want that, I recommend you **[edit]** to make that clear. Otherwise, I recommend you **[edit]** about what you do need. Did @PerlDuck's comment answer your question? Do you want `sudo` not to require a password? Does sudhir want a root shell (as with `sudo -i`)?

Comment: I have updated sudoers file saved (ctrl+) & exited (ctrl+x).

Comment: @PerlDuck Im trying run command fdisk -l with user "sudhir" without sudo command infront. Just like the root user.